# Are char8_t and char16_t dynamic in size?

Tags: c++, utf-8, char, utf-16, utf

Here is what I know:

- "[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length character encoding standard used for electronic communication."
- Likewise, UTF-16 is a variable-length character encoding.

Here is what I wonder:

- Are `char8_t` and `char16` in C++ are dynamic in size too (to fit in the generic behaviour of `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`)?
- Will it ever happen that when I assign it a *specical* value, it automatically expands its own size to match?

Comment: No and No. They are 8 and 16 bits respectively.

Comment: They are just glorified versions of `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` respectively.

Comment: @tkausl , what is the type in C++ that we can actually simulate the behavior of the standard UTF-8 and UTF-16 ? :)

Comment: C++ has no support of UTF-8 or UTF-16, you'll need to use third-party libraries (such as ICU) if you want to work properly with Unicode text.

Comment: @user7860670 oh, I thought C++ can do everything

Comment: Being able to do everything and providing functionality for everything are not the same thing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, I didn't realize it all those years long :<

Comment: @Crackie The underlying data storage to use for utf-8 would be a (possibly unsigned) char array, preferably that within a vector, or even more preferably, within a custom class.

Comment: As a general rule, all types in C++ have a constant size; `sizeof(anything)` is a constant expression. (That is not true for C with variable length arrays.)

Comment: But I feel your pain regarding language resp. standard library support for common things which other languages have supported seemingly forever.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica , thanks :) . I can't just sleep very well with C++. Not sure where I am now and when i can stop learning C++

Comment: @user7860670 No, you generally don't need ICU or any other library to work properly with Unicode text. Plain old string API is sufficient for 99% of people 100% of the time.

Comment: *"when i can stop learning C++"* - probably never, considering the pace at which standard committee keeps dumping random useless stuff at the new language iterations.

Comment: You can stop learning C++ when you stop using C++.

Comment: So the size of the underlying datatype is fixed. The actual strings may vary in length and not be directly related to the number of symbols in the string due to encoding where a character my need more then one char8_t or char16_t to be represented.

Comment: I have been using C++ since 1995 and I am still learning, make that your mindset too. Anything you learn today may get a better solution tomorrow so always be able to re-invent yourself as a software engineer (and a person too ;)

Comment: `char8_t` is a UTF-8 *encoding unit* (8 bits).  `char16_t` is a UTF-16 *encoding unit* (16 bits).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI *"Plain old string API is sufficient for 99% of people 100% of the time."* - more like 99% of people are trying to stick with plain old ASCII whenever possible to avoid dealing with unicode mess...

Comment: Oh, it is quite painful to hear, my teacher never told me that. Not sure i did a happy marrage with C++.

Comment: @user7860670 No, it's more like people discover that characters are not what they used to be, and they need a huge library to support characters, instead of simply forgetting that characters exist and using strings as their basic building blocks of text. At most they need UTF-8 validation to sanitize their input.

Comment: @@Sir. Pepijn Kramer, 1995 upto now, it was a long trip for me. Hopefully I'm not reminding you about those young old days when you started struggling with C++, Sir :)

Comment: @user7860670 `char8_t` is useless on a platform where `iostream`s are interacting with utf8 in the outside world, and `char16_t` is useless where `wiostream`s are interacting with utf16 in the outside world. Ime there are plenty of platforms where at least one of those is not true. It would be nice if there were some aliases for u8 and u16 in `<regex>` and similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> char8_t and char16_t are dynamic in size?

No.

> Are char8_t and char16_t in C++ are dynamic in size too (to fit in the generic behaviour of UTF-8 and UTF-16) ?

No.

> Will it ever happen that when I assign it a "special" value, it will automatically expand its own size to match?

No.